# CouchDB: add timestamp on insert and update

Tags: validation, timestamp, couchdb

How I can add or update timestamp on document when it changes? Currently I have `date` field, which set from app, but that is not secure and right way if anyone can set time.

I'm tried with `validate_doc_update`, but no luck: it don't save `newDoc` changes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to send **all** your changes through [update handlers](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html#update-functions).

To be clear, that means normal writes to the database will not set these timestamps, so you can only reliably do this if your database isn't exposed publicly.

Comment: Update handlers works between network and storage or run after record been saved? 

Can I change received document on the fly or not?

Comment: An update handler is what receives your write request and then whatever changes it makes are saved into the database.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a solution, this was my implementation of the solution: I used Dominic Barnes response. Here how I implemented it. In the _design/$design_name, I added

```
{
  "_id": "<design_name>",
  "_rev": "<rev_id>",
  "language": "javascript",
  "views": {
    "some_view_name": {
      "map": "function(doc){emit(doc.id,doc);}"
    }
  },
  "updates": {
    "update_timestamp": "function(doc, req){ 
      if (req && req.body) { 
        var newDoc = JSON.parse(req.body); 
        newDoc['timestamp'] = Date.now().toString(); 
        return [newDoc, JSON.stringify({'ok': true})];
      }
    }"
  }
}
```

Careful, the "update_timestamp" function should be on one line because it is a json file, so like this:

```
"updates": {
    "update_timestamp": "function(doc, req){ if (req && req.body) { var newDoc = JSON.parse(req.body); newDoc['timestamp'] = Date.now().toString(); return [newDoc, JSON.stringify({'ok': true})];}}"
}
```

and then, I call it using a PUT request with the URL: `<couch_db_url>/<db_name>/_design/<design_name>/_update/update_timestamp/<id_doc>`
and adding the document in the body.